# Error in Update Data using php and mysql in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

In this example while inserting record in MySql database there is no problem but will update recode it give following [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VQuDq.png)
In **EditProductActivity.java** all records have to update .

**EditProductActivity.java**

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EditProductActivity extends Activity {

    EditText txtName;
    EditText txtPrice;
    EditText txtDesc;
    EditText txtCreatedAt;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String pid;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // JSON parser class
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // single product url
    private static final String url_product_detials = "http://192.168.1.2/android_connect/get_product_details.php";

    // url to update product
    private static final String url_update_product = "http://192.168.1.2/android_connect/update_product.php";

    // url to delete product
    private static final String url_delete_product = "http://192.168.1.2/android_connect/delete_product.php";

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
    private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
    private static final String TAG_PRICE = "price";
    private static final String TAG_DESCRIPTION = "description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.edit_product);

        // save button
        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        // getting product details from intent
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // getting product id (pid) from intent
        pid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_PID);

        // Getting complete product details in background thread
        new GetProductDetails().execute();

        // save button click event
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // starting background task to update product
                new SaveProductDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        // Delete button click event
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // deleting product in background thread
                new DeleteProduct().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
     * */
    class GetProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Getting product details in background thread
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // Check for success tag
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Building Parameters
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                        // getting product details by making HTTP request
                        // Note that product details url will use GET request
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                                url_product_detials, "GET", params);

                        // check your log for json response
                        Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                        // json success tag
                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // successfully received product details
                            JSONArray productObj = json
                                    .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                            // get first product object from JSON Array
                            JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // product with this pid found
                            // Edit Text
                            txtName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
                            txtPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputPrice);
                            txtDesc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputDesc);

                            // display product data in EditText
                            txtName.setText(product.getString(TAG_NAME));
                            txtPrice.setText(product.getString(TAG_PRICE));
                            txtDesc.setText(product.getString(TAG_DESCRIPTION));

                        }else{
                            // product with pid not found
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once got all details
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to  Save product Details
     * */
    class SaveProductDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving product ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        /**
         * Saving product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // getting updated data from EditTexts
            String name = txtName.getText().toString();
            String price = txtPrice.getText().toString();
            String description = txtDesc.getText().toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PID, pid));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_NAME, name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_PRICE, price));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_DESCRIPTION, description));

            // sending modified data through http request
            // Notice that update product url accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_product,
                    "POST", params);

            // check json success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully updated
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product update
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to update product
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product uupdated
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /*****************************************************************
     * Background Async Task to Delete Product
     * */
    class DeleteProduct extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditProductActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Deleting Product...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Deleting product
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pid", pid));

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_delete_product, "POST", params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // product successfully deleted
                    // notify previous activity by sending code 100
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // send result code 100 to notify about product deletion
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();

        }

    }
}
```

**JSONParser.java**

```
package com.example.androidhive;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
            List<NameValuePair> params) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }           


        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

**update_product.php**

```
 <?php

/*
 * Following code will update a product information
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['pid']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $pid = $_POST['pid'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];

    // include db connect class
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

    // connecting to db
    $db = new DB_CONNECT();

    // mysql update row with matched pid
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE products SET name = '$name', price = '$price', description = '$description' WHERE pid = $pid");

    // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully updated
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Product successfully updated.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
    } else {

    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: If you spend some time narrowing down your question people are much more likely to help. Copying and pasting multiple entire files means people have to read through hundreds of lines of code, when the problem will lie in maybe a handful of lines. Spending some time finding the problem and reducing the amount of code you post will improve your stack overflow experience!

Comment: You are getting a NetworkOnMainThreadException  change makeHttpRequest() to an Async Task. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/how-to-fix-android-os-networkonmainthreadexception

Comment: HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet); give error but what is it I don't get it.